# Keep Android App running while device is locked

Tags: android, service, location, locationmanager

as the title says i need to run my app on my android device while my device is locked or sleeping. My problem is that i am logging GPS coordinates and the app stops when it turns in the sleeping mode. I tried to create a service but i really do not understand how this works. I've checked nearly every article i have found on Google or on this forum but the code i have found was always incomplete. I do not want to copy & paste everything i want to understand this. Therefore a complete tutorial of how to run a locationmanager as service to get the current location back would be great :).

Greetz

[EDIT]:

Ok i have looked into the FusedLocationProvider and this is what i have made of it:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GPSService extends Service implements LocationListener, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private boolean requestingLocationUpdate=true;

private double latitude;
private double longitude;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
    }
@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("GPSService", "onCreate");

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("GPSService", "onDestroy");
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) 
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("GPSService", "onStart");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    updateContent(loc);
}

private void updateContent(Location loc)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Location changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    latitude = loc.getLatitude();
    longitude = loc.getLongitude();
}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    if(requestingLocationUpdate)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest,this);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Started the location update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,this);
}


}
```

This works fine and i receive a toast when my app runs in the background and the location is changing. My next steps will be to send the coordinates back to my MainActivity. Is this where the BroadcastReceiver comes in ?

Greetz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first off, try looking into the FusedLocationProvider API. This builds upon the new GoogleApiClient and the services offered therein.

As far as tutorials go, I'll give you a brief little snippet.

The basic concept is that you register a BroadcastReceiver in your application that "listens" for certain services. As far as code as concerned, you would best be served by looking this up in the docs or in the numerous examples that the Developers site has to offer.

With the Broadcast Receiver in place, you would then issue PendingIntents using one of the method signatures that requestLocationUpdates() provides.

There are other particulars but start with these ideas and check out [these](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) docs

EDIT:

If you're looking to store a lot of coordinates, using an intermediate storage system like a Sqlite database would be a good place to start. If you're receiving to updating the view, then you would have to implement some sort of callback to your activity.

Comment: I save the GPS coordinates in special XML file which i need for later (it has to be xml but you are right Sqlite would be a much better start). Once i received the coordinates in my MainActivity i write them into the xml file and i want i want to give a little feedback to the user to show him that the device is actually recording something. So somehow i have to "send" the coordinates back to it. You mentioned callback. Can you explain what exactly you mean or give me some more information that i can start my own research about this, please ?

Comment: The basic concept is that you have an interface. This interface is then implemented by all classes that need to be updated new data being obtained. You hand a reference to this class to your GPSLogger class. @OneSoft additionally, consider moving your GPS methods into a strictly model class. Implementing a Service runs off the main thread and if you're getting a lot of points you're gonna slow yourself down quite a bit.

Comment: Ok i solved my problem with the BroadcastReceiver. Thank you for your help it is working now.

Comment: If my answers helped solve your question please mark it as resolved with the opaque check mark next to the answer. Glad it's working. you're welcome